# Установка Firefox определённой версии через терминал в Linux

Tags: linux, firefox

После обновления FF на 55.0 многие расширения стали устаревшими.Дополнительно лаги в ВК,а именно при переходе на страницу любого,вернуться обратно нажав на кнопку "новости" или любую другую - не получается.Попробовал очистить куки и кэш,но ничего.Думаю,может баги именно в версии FF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в программе linux — никак. она предназначена совсем для других задач.

в операционной же системе gnu/linux — уже попроще. чтобы не пересобирать, можно воспользоваться какой-нибудь предыдущей версией из репозитория вашего дистрибутива. на каком-нибудь из зеркал наверняка будут лежат старые (технически уже не входящие в состав репозитория) пакеты.

так как название дистрибутива вы не указали, приведу два примера для наиболее популярных:

- ubuntu: вот они, россыпи предыдущих сборок программы firefox: http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/
- debian: тоже кое-что имеется: http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/pool/main/f/firefox/

скачать файл с пакетом можно, например, программой *wget* (или любой другой из тысяч прочих реализаций http-клиентов).

установить — в разных пакетных системах по-разному. в пакетных системах *dpkg* и *rpm* — одноимёнными командами:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i путь/к/файлу
$ sudo rpm -i путь/к/файлу
```

Comment: @stackflow `aptitude install firefox=45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1` - для ubuntu 16.04. А вообще такая фигня возникает из-за необновлённых дополнений. Попробуй или без них или сначала перейти на старый фокс, обновить дополнения, а потом обновиться.

Comment: *А что за программа linux ?* — та самая, которая выполняет функции ядра в ряде операционных систем — к примеру, в gnu/linux, или в dalvik/linux (android). сама по себе операционной системой эта программа, естественно, не является.

Comment: @stackflow alexandr имеет в виду это - https://www.gnu.org/gnu/why-gnu-linux.ru.html

Comment: @Hellseher, плюс здравый смысл и мнение таких людей, как Таненбаум, Столлингз, Вахалия (ну, для тех, кому один Столман недостаточно авторитетен) в определении понятия «операционная система».